# Magento 1.9.0.1 product image upload issue

Tags: magento-1.9, error, product-images, image-upload

I installed version 1.9.0.1 of Magento CE on a dedicated server.

Everything works fine except when my customer uploads images for the products: he selects a bunch of images, clicks upload, the first one goes fine but then it gets slower every picture until it prints SSL certificate error on Firefox or the progress gets stuck at 100% for some minutes on other browsers.

On top of this, it doesn't happen to me and it looks like it happens when there are two or more people inserting products with images.

I disabled SSL from the back office and set every URL without using the {{base_url}} variable but I guess it's not a real SSL problem.

Can anyone help me?

Maybe you have some advice or can you tell me how to debug the upload process?

Thank you!

Comment: Does you media folder has required permission ? is it replicable with your customer with your credentials ? If so there can be permission issue.

Comment: media directory has permission 0777, so do its subfolders.
UPDATE: reindexes are set on automatic, yet some of them keep on having "update required" set to "yes" while "status" is on green.
A customer paying with bank transfer caused "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded".
Could it all be tied together?

Comment: It can be, what is the timeout property, it might be case that maximum response allowed time is reached and as it is ajax call you might not be getting error and hence blank page...

Comment: you mean php timeout? is there any other timeout setting (apache, mysql...)?
If more than one user login to the backoffice with the same account, is it an issue?

Comment: This does not seems like a duplicate question since the suggested link doesnt contain any valid answer and seems to have two different context.